# How to read Name & IP Addresses from file?

Tags: powershell

I have a file(.txt) with the following per line format for the contents:

```
<Name>     <IPAddress>
```

For example, the file contents can be:

```
Tampa Server    10.73.202.91   
Hollywood Server    10.73.203.91   
Coconut Server  10.73.204.91   
Brighton Server 10.73.206.91    
Bollywood Server    10.73.207.91
```

How to read the IP Addresses into an array efficiently ?

Comment: Use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks

Comment: @Monku Even questions should have a persistent value for follow-up readers to not get down-voted/put on hold. You possibly should take the [tour] and [ask] (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the comments above mean is that you should show your work, what you researched, where you have questions, etc. as you are new to PowerShell, so others can guess what you may know, or don't know.

For example, do you know how to read a file, parse it, use regular expressions, pscustomobject, and more?

```
$datafile = @'
Tampa Server    10.73.202.91   
Hollywood Server    10.73.203.91   
Coconut Server  10.73.204.91   
Brighton Server 10.73.206.91    
Bollywood Server    10.73.207.91
'@

$data = $datafile -split "`n"

$data.count

$obj = @()

$data | % {
    $line = $_
    $matches = [regex]::Matches($line, "(.*)(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)")
    $obj += [pscustomobject]@{'Name'=$matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); 'IP'=$matches.Groups[2].Value;}
    }

$obj
```

Answer (score 0):

this gets the job done.

```
 $ServerAddressArray = @()
 $file #Set to file path here
 ForEach ($line in Get-Content $file)
 {
      $Columns = "ServerName", "IP"
      $Data = ConvertFrom-csv -inputobject $line -Header $Columns -Delimiter "`t"
      $ipAddress = $Data[0].IP.replace(' ', '');
      $ipAddress = $ipAddress.replace('`t', '');
      $ServerAddressArray+=$ipAddress
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file uses multiple spaces as a delimiter what `Import-Csv` can't handle.

But there is a work around use `Get-Content` to replace these spaces with a single character

Emulating the file with a here string

```
$Content = @"
Tampa Server    10.73.202.91   
Hollywood Server    10.73.203.91   
Coconut Server  10.73.204.91   
Brighton Server 10.73.206.91    
Bollywood Server    10.73.207.91
"@ -replace ' +(?=\d)','|'

$data = $Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,IPAddress -Delimiter '|'
$data
# $data | Out-Gridview
# $data | Export-Csv '.\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Similar to Korys answer but using a regular expresson with a lookahead to use only spaces followed by a (nonconsuming) digit as a delimiter.

The output to a Gridview and exporting to a csv file are optional/commented out.

Sample output:

```
Name             IPAddress
----             ---------
Tampa Server     10.73.202.91
Hollywood Server 10.73.203.91
Coconut Server   10.73.204.91
Brighton Server  10.73.206.91
Bollywood Server 10.73.207.91
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about using raw, split and join on the content...

```
(Get-Content -Path D:\Temp\ServerIpaList.txt -Raw) -split '\s+(?=\d)' -join ',' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,IPAddress 

Name             IPAddress    
----             ---------    
Tampa Server     10.73.202.91 
Hollywood Server 10.73.203.91 
Coconut Server   10.73.204.91 
Brighton Server  10.73.206.91 
Bollywood Server 10.73.207.91
```